# Deezer iOS SDK - DZRTrack - Obtaining "alternative" track when readable is false

Tags: ios, objective-c, deezer

I'm using the new Deezer iOS SDK (0.9.0) and I need to find the alternative track (if there is one) when the returned track has its `readable` property set to `NO`.

This is the track that I am testing with: http://www.deezer.com/track/95029960

It is not available in the UK (where I am) but there is an alternative track available.

Here is the API response when I query the track in the API Explorer (from the UK):

```
{
  "id": 95029960,
  "readable": false,
  "title": "Looking To Hide (Radio Edit)",
  "isrc": "DKUCA1400209",
  "link": "http://www.deezer.com/track/95029960",
  "share": "http://www.deezer.com/track/95029960?utm_source=deezer&utm_content=track-95029960&utm_term=0_1427961877&utm_medium=web",
  "duration": 198,
  "track_position": 52,
  "disk_number": 1,
  "rank": 95640,
  "explicit_lyrics": false,
  "preview": "http://cdn-preview-0.deezer.com/stream/0fc9584d259b89c248e9bf6ccdb1a7bc-3.mp3",
  "bpm": 0,
  "gain": 0,
  "available_countries": [
    "DK",
    "IS"
  ],
  "alternative": {
    "id": 87700625,
    "readable": true,
    "title": "Looking to Hide",
    "isrc": "DKUCA1400209",
    "link": "http://www.deezer.com/track/87700625",
    "share": "http://www.deezer.com/track/87700625?utm_source=deezer&utm_content=track-87700625&utm_term=0_1427961877&utm_medium=web",
    "duration": 199,
    "track_position": 1,
    "disk_number": 1,
    "rank": 50142,
    "explicit_lyrics": false,
    "preview": "http://cdn-preview-e.deezer.com/stream/e7758b15d4d0b08dc6c69e617f16c46a-2.mp3",
    "bpm": 0,
    "gain": 0,
    "available_countries": [
      "AD",
      "AE",
      "AF",

      ...

      "ZM",
      "ZW"
    ],
    "contributors": [
      {
        "id": 1627159,
        "name": "Nadia Gattas",
        "link": "http://www.deezer.com/artist/1627159",
        "share": "http://www.deezer.com/artist/1627159?utm_source=deezer&utm_content=artist-1627159&utm_term=0_1427961877&utm_medium=web",
        "picture": "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/1627159/image",
        "radio": false,
        "tracklist": "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/1627159/top?limit=50",
        "role": "Main",
        "type": "artist"
      }
    ],
    "artist": {
      "id": 1627159,
      "name": "Nadia Gattas",
      "link": "http://www.deezer.com/artist/1627159",
      "share": "http://www.deezer.com/artist/1627159?utm_source=deezer&utm_content=artist-1627159&utm_term=0_1427961877&utm_medium=web",
      "picture": "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/1627159/image",
      "radio": false,
      "tracklist": "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/1627159/top?limit=50",
      "type": "artist"
    },
    "album": {
      "id": 8853909,
      "title": "Looking to Hide",
      "link": "http://www.deezer.com/album/8853909",
      "cover": "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/album/8853909/image",
      "release_date": "2014-10-27",
      "tracklist": "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/album/8853909/tracks",
      "type": "album"
    },
    "type": "track"
  },
  "contributors": [
    {
      "id": 1627159,
      "name": "Nadia Gattas",
      "link": "http://www.deezer.com/artist/1627159",
      "share": "http://www.deezer.com/artist/1627159?utm_source=deezer&utm_content=artist-1627159&utm_term=0_1427961877&utm_medium=web",
      "picture": "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/1627159/image",
      "radio": false,
      "tracklist": "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/1627159/top?limit=50",
      "role": "Main",
      "type": "artist"
    },
    {
      "id": 1627159,
      "name": "Nadia Gattas",
      "link": "http://www.deezer.com/artist/1627159",
      "share": "http://www.deezer.com/artist/1627159?utm_source=deezer&utm_content=artist-1627159&utm_term=0_1427961877&utm_medium=web",
      "picture": "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/1627159/image",
      "radio": false,
      "tracklist": "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/1627159/top?limit=50",
      "role": "Featured",
      "type": "artist"
    }
  ],
  "artist": {
    "id": 1627159,
    "name": "Nadia Gattas",
    "link": "http://www.deezer.com/artist/1627159",
    "share": "http://www.deezer.com/artist/1627159?utm_source=deezer&utm_content=artist-1627159&utm_term=0_1427961877&utm_medium=web",
    "picture": "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/1627159/image",
    "radio": false,
    "tracklist": "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/1627159/top?limit=50",
    "type": "artist"
  },
  "album": {
    "id": 9667910,
    "title": "Dance Chart 41",
    "link": "http://www.deezer.com/album/9667910",
    "cover": "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/album/9667910/image",
    "release_date": "2015-02-23",
    "tracklist": "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/album/9667910/tracks",
    "type": "album"
  },
  "type": "track"
}
```

As you can see, `readable` is `false` but `alternative.readable` is `true`. In this case, I want to use the id of the `alternative` track because the original track isn't available in my country.

Based on this response, I can simply just pull the alternative identifier out and use that however because I'm using the new Deezer iOS SDK I can't seem to do this..

Following the documentation, I use the following code to obtain all the values I need from the API:

```
// the manager to use in the requests
DZRRequestManager *manager = [DZRRequestManager defaultManager];
// the keys we wish to obtain
NSArray *keys = @[ @"id", @"readable", @"alternative.id", @"alternative.readable" ];
// the track id
NSString *identifier = @"95029960";
// fetch the track
[DZRTrack objectWithIdentifier:identifier requestManager:manager callback:^(DZRTrack *track, NSError *error) {
    // fetch the keys
    [track valuesForKeyPaths:keys withRequestManager:manager callback:^(NSDictionary *values, NSError *keyPathsError) {
        // log what we got.
        NSLog(@"Got Values: %@", values);
    }];
}];
```

Now, I was expecting to get all 4 values back providing they are present in the JSON api response (which they are) but I get the following output:

```
2015-04-02 09:48:35.485 <redacted>[694:115244] Got Values: {
    id = 95029960;
    readable = 0;
}
```

I then took at look at the `track`'s `supportedInfoKeys` and `alternative` doesn't appear to be present. Why is this?

Is there an alternative way to fetch the alternative track within the Deezer iOS SDK?

---

### Update:

I was asked to check the `keyPathsError` being returned.. Something I hadn't done before as I was unaware that you could get back both the `values` and the `keyPathsError` at the same time however I have the following error being set:

```
Domain: DZRModelErrorDomain,
Code: 4,
UserInfo: {
    "NSLocalizedDescriptionKey" : "Some object could not be parsed",
    "DZROriginalErrorsKey" : [
        {
            Domain: DZRModelErrorDomain,
            Code: 4,
            UserInfo: {
                "NSLocalizedDescriptionKey" : "You requested and unknown key from Deezer Object",
                "DZRRequestedPropertyKey" : "alternative"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This obviously suggests that i've tried to obtain an unsupported key, but why is that unsupported?

Comment: Can you check what is in the `keyPathsError` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a supported key because the SDK's player does not take into account the alternatives yet, I guess it will soon do. You can go around this limitation by a little method swizzling.

So you need to create a category on DZRTrack and swizzle `-[DZRObject supportedInfoKeys]` to add the key `alternative` at the end of the array. This alone will give you a "property" `alternative` on `DZRTrack`'s instances which will be a `NSDictionary` with the content of the JSON.

You can go a little further though and get back full fledge `DZRTrack` object for the alternative. The SDK when it parse the response from the API seems to, at some point, look for a `parseFoo:error:` method on the instance. So by putting a method `parseAlternative:error:` method in your category, you can parse the JSON and get, the DZRTrack object. For this you will need to use a private API of the SDK : `+[DZROject objectFromJSON:error:]`.

Included is the implementation of the category.

```
@interface DZRObject (AlternativeTrack)
+ (id)objectFromJSON:(id)JSON error:(NSError **)error;
@end

@implementation DZRTrack (AlternativeTrack)
+ (void)load
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        Class aClass = [self class];

        SEL original = @selector(supportedInfoKeys);
        SEL swizzled = @selector(alternativeTrack_supportedInfoKeys);

        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(aClass, original);
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(aClass, swizzled);

        BOOL didAddMethod = class_addMethod(aClass, original,
            method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
            method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));
        if (didAddMethod) {
            class_replaceMethod(aClass, swizzled,
                method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        }
        else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }
    });
}

- (NSArray *)alternativeTrack_supportedInfoKeys
{
    return [[self alternativeTrack_supportedInfoKeys] arrayByAddingObject:@"alternative"];
}

- (id)parseAlternative:(id)JSON error:(NSError **)error
{
    return [DZRObject objectFromJSON:JSON error:error];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this fix works correctly.. If I call `-[DZRTrack valuesForKeyPaths:withRequestManager:callback:]` when there is an "alternative" track in the API then the completion block gets called however if the "alternative" track isn't present in the API response then the completion block never gets called when parsing. Looks like I would need to first somehow check if the alternative field is going to be present for the track before requesting the alternative key. Could we maybe get an update to the SDK instead with a proper fix?

Comment: You are right, there is a bug preventing the callback to be called if an intermediate value is `nil` in a keypath. This will be fixed in the next release of the SDK. Alternatively, if you are blocked, you could ask for the `alternative` of a track with the `[DZRObject valueForKey:error:callback:]` method. This call will result in your callback being called by the SDK and then query for the values on the alternative track.